# Converting decimal to hex with Erlang?

Tags: erlang

How to convert the decimal "37" to the hex Value "25" in Erlang? Is there a simple way?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`integer_to_list(Integer, Base) -> string()` transforms an integer to a list of any base you supply: http://erldocs.com/18.3/erts/erlang.html?i=3&search=integer_to#integer_to_list/2

Comment: You're welcome! http://erldocs.com/ is a great site to search for Erlang methods.

Answer (score 2):

A little simpler solution: `httpd_util:integer_to_hexlist(Number) -> HexString`